# Vaadin with JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, vaadin7

I'm looking for a solution to create reports using JasperReports for my application. I found some examples but still could not make it work. I'm using Vaadin7

I'm trying this

```
public class Report {

public Report(){
    createShowReport();
}

private void createShowReport(){
    final Map map = new HashMap();

    StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
        public InputStream getStream() {
            byte[] b = null;
            try {
                b = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("br/ind/ibg/reports/report3.jasper"), map, new JREmptyDataSource());
            } catch (JRException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        }
    };


    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, "report3.pdf");
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

    VerticalLayout v = new VerticalLayout();
    Embedded e = new Embedded("", resource);
    e.setSizeFull();
    e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
    v.addComponent(e);

    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setContent(v);
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(w);
}


private Window getWindow(){
    Window w = new Window();
    w.setSizeFull();
    w.center();
    return w;
}
```

}

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be on the `JasperPrint printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(file, parametros,dados);` line.

Make sure that your report is found (`file` is not null).

In order to show the report, what I usually do is put the resulted pdf in a stream, then create a `streamResource` with `mimeType='application\pdf'` and use `window.open(resource)` to show it.

Example:

```
StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

                public InputStream getStream() {
                    byte[] b = null;
                    try {
                        b = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("reports/report3.jasper"), map, con);
                    } catch (JRException ex) {
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
                }
            };

            StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, "report3.pdf", getApplication());
            resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

            getApplication().getMainWindow().open(resource, "_new");
```

Comment: I'm using maven and created the package:br.ind.ibg.reports and added the report3.jasper inside but returns file not found and this exception. Any idea ?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing you folder structure. At the beginning of the createShowReport function create a file, like  `File f = new File("a.txt");
  System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());`. This will show you the current location, where it is actually searching for the report file as well.

Comment: I did: String reportFile="br/ind/ibg/reports/report3.jasper";
And loaded the file, but now I can't view the report.

Comment: You are not showing your result. I don't know if there is any method to add a JRViewer to a window, but see my updated answer for a way to show the report.

Comment: I changed the method and now is showing a window to download the report. I want to show report in my web browser. The method open() is depreciated on vaadin7. I've edited the post with changes.

Comment: You could try Embedded. Like: `Embedded e = new Embedded();e.setSizeFull();e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);e.setSource(resource);window.addComponent(e);`